# How to randomize a dictionary in python 2.7.4?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, random

I'm sort of new to coding but this question has been nagging me for a while. I'm trying to randomize a dictionary so that every time I play the game I will get a different scene. I then want it to return that scene so that I can play that one. Here is the script:

```
from sys import exit
import time
import random
#import another file here to use in this

class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "Not yet configured."



class Start():

    def start(self):
        print "Hello. How are you? You are about to play a game that is set in a crazy world."
        print "We are creating your profile right now."
        epic = raw_input("Enter your name here: ")
        print "Hello, %s." % epic
        print "You are being transported to a randomly generated world. Try to survive as long as possible."
        print "Here's some advice, %s: Don't die. Make the right choice. Be careful." % epic
        print "The rules will be shown to you soon."
        print "LOADING..."
        time.sleep(1)
        return Rules().rules()

class Rules(Scene):

    def rules(self):
        print ""
        print "-------------"
        print ""
        print "These are the rules:"
        print "1: Be a good sport. This game takes skill and memory to be able to win, so try your best to succeed."
        print "2: Every time you die, you do not get to respawn, so you will be prompted to either just not play anymore"
        print "or play again. If you decide to play again, you will most likely be on a new world with a new puzzles."
        print "3: Finally, have fun. Hopefully this game brings you joy, so have a great time playing it."
        return random.choice(Map.shuffler.keys())

class BoilerRoom(Scene):

    def boiler_room(self):
        print "You are in the boiler room."

class Kitchen(Scene):

    def kitchen(self):
        print "You are in the kitchen."

class Pool(Scene):

    def pool(self):
        print "You are in the pool."

class TennisCourts():

    def tennis_courts(self):
        print "You are in the tennis courts."

class SoccerField():

    def soccer_field(self):
        print "You are on the soccer field."

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        Rules(): 'rules',
        BoilerRoom(): 'boiler_room',
        Kitchen(): 'kitchen',
        Pool(): 'pool',
        TennisCourts(): 'tennis_courts',
        SoccerField(): 'soccer_field'
    }

    shuffler = {
        BoilerRoom(): 'boiler_room',
        Kitchen(): 'kitchen',
        Pool(): 'pool',
        TennisCourts(): 'tennis_courts',
        SoccerField(): 'soccer_field'
    }


Start().start()
```

Comment: Dictionary keys are already random. Ie., there is no ordering guarantees. However If you are just using Maps.shuffler to keep the scenes initialized, why not use a regular list ?

Also What is the current behavior ?

Comment: So are you saying i should convert my dictionary to a list and then do random.choice that way? Im trying to get it to randomize the rooms so that each time a player plays it then they will get a new room.

Comment: All I said is that having randomizing dict.keys() and or directly over a list is going to give you similar results. Unless there is any specific reason, you don't need a dict. Also, by the look of it, it should be returning random rooms anyway. Hence the question "what's the current behavior"?

Comment: See my answer in your second, almost identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195991/cant-randomize-list-with-classes-inside-of-it-python-2-7-4

Comment: Why are you mapping from an object-> string? having the dict the other way round seems like it would be much easier to handle.